# suggestions about which version to use

Tags: versions

I am using Asus motherboard m2n-mx see plus
And amd Athlon 64 x2 processor
On my desktop.
Which version of ubuntu for my system, 
And it will also let me install the graphics card software on it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For version look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). For graphic driver look at this pages from Ubuntu documentation:

[For Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

[For AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)